# Como baixar um BD pelo console?

Tags: mysql

Preciso baixar um banco de dados na minha máquina, mas ela não aguenta o MySQL Workbench.

Existe algum outro programa mais leve que o Workbench ou quais os comandos pra eu baixar o BD que eu quero?

Comment: Uma boa opção é o "antigo" MySQL Query Browser, caso vc queira uma GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o MySQLdump:

`mysqldump [dbname] -h [host] -u [user] -p > [endereço onde salvar o dump]` 
pressione enter

digite a senha e pronto